# What happens to my saved game if I buy a new 3ds

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

What happens to my saved game (Retail version not eShop) when I buy a new 3DS when my old one gets broken? I a case of total destruction of a 3DS system an you don't have the chance to make data transfer... Everybody says that saved games are being stored on the game cartridge but when I put my game in a new 3DS am I only able to play as a resident?

Comment: Can you explain what happened in more detail? You broke your old 3DS, and when you put your Animal Crossing cartridge into the new system, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

The save game on a physical copy of Animal Crossing: New Leaf is stored on the cartridge. If your system is destroyed but you still have the cartridge then you can resume playing on another system. I have a cartridge that I swap between two systems so I can confirm this.

Now what I can't confirm is if there is something strange going on with your New 3DS. This is something that you might want to contact Nintendo Customer Support about for further guidance.

Answer (score -2):

Just go onto the Nintendo e-shop and download the Nintendo 3ds transfer app (it will look like a toaster). Then do the same on the new 3ds, and then all of the memory on your old one will be on your new one (not sure if that works for game cards though).

Comment: OP is asking about a case when the original system is broken, so a system transfer can't be made. There is also no specific app necessary for system transfer, the capability is part of the 3DS. You might be thinking of the Save Data Transfer Tool, which transfers the save data from a cartridge game to a digital copy of the same game, provided you have both available.